# Stacked barplot in ggplot of numeric values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot monthly average precipitation broken down into snow and rain in a stacked barplot. From searching around on this site I found some code that does what I want, however, since I am not fully understanding the code I am not able to change the aesthetics of it.

Below is the code that creates the plot that I want, but it looks..well .. a little "ugly". Usually when working with ggplot I save the plot to a variable and then keep adding and changing things. Since in this code the plot function is embedded I don't know how to save the plot output to a variable.

```
correct_order <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
                   "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
cn %>% group_by(Months) %>%
  summarise(Rain = mean(rain_mm,na.rm = TRUE),Snow = mean(snow_cm,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  gather(Legend, Precipitation, -Months) %>%
  ggplot(.,aes(x = Months, y = Precipitation, 
               group = Legend, color = Legend)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=correct_order) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Below is a dput of my dataset.

```
structure(list(Months = structure(c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 
9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 
10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 
4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("Apr", 
"Aug", "Dec", "Feb", "Jan", "Jul", "Jun", "Mar", "May", "Nov", 
"Oct", "Sep"), class = "factor"), station = structure(c(7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), .Label = c("albernirob", "blackcreeek", 
"campbellrivairp", "campbellrivsurf", "capemudge", "comoxairp", 
"courtney", "mudbay", "oysterriver", "powriv", "powrivairp", 
"qualicumhatch", "qualicumriverres", "stillwater"), class = "factor"), 
    temp_davg_c = c(3, 3.6, 5.7, 9.1, 12.5, 15.5, 17.9, 17.6, 
    14.2, 9, 5.1, 3.1, 2.8, 3.4, 5.4, 8.5, 11.7, 14.8, 17.1, 
    16.9, 13.6, 8.6, 5, 2.8, 2.4, 3.2, 5.2, 8, 11.6, 14.7, 17.3, 
    17.2, 13.7, 8.6, 4.4, 2.1, 2.6, 3.8, 5.9, 7.4, 11.5, 14.3, 
    16.2, 17.2, 12.7, 8.1, 4.1, NA, 4.1, 4.6, 6.3, 8.8, 12.1, 
    14.9, 17.2, 17.1, 14.2, 9.6, 5.8, 3.8, 3.9, 4.3, 6.1, 8.8, 
    12.4, 15.5, 18, 17.9, 14.5, 9.5, 5.7, 3.5, 3.5, 4, 5.9, 8.6, 
    12.1, 15.1, 17.5, 17.4, 14.1, 9.3, 5.3, 3.1, 3.3, 3.8, 5.6, 
    8.3, 12, 15.1, 17.3, 17.2, 13.6, 8.9, 5.2, 3.2, 3.9, 4.2, 
    5.9, 8.6, 12, 14.9, 17.1, 16.7, 13.6, 9.2, 5.6, 3.5, 2.8, 
    3.7, 5.8, 8.5, 11.9, 14.9, 17.3, 17.4, 14.1, 9.2, 4.9, 2.6, 
    2, 3, 5.7, 8.5, 12.3, 15.5, 18.3, 18.5, 15.3, 9.8, 4.6, 1.8, 
    4.6, 5.1, 7, 9.6, 13, 15.8, 18.4, 18.6, 15.6, 10.8, 6.8, 
    4.3, 3.6, 3.9, 5.9, 8.6, 11.9, 14.9, 17.2, 17.2, 14.1, 9.4, 
    5.3, 3.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    temp_dmax_c = c(5.6, 7.1, 10, 14.3, 18.1, 21, 23.8, 23.7, 
    20.1, 13, 8, 5.4, 5.8, 7.4, 10, 13.9, 17.3, 20.2, 22.9, 22.8, 
    19.6, 13, 8.4, 5.4, 5.5, 7.2, 9.7, 13.2, 17, 20.1, 23, 23.3, 
    19.8, 13.1, 7.7, 4.9, 5.6, 7.5, 10.6, 12.2, 16.7, 19.5, 21.6, 
    23.2, 18, 12.3, 7.5, NA, 6.6, 7.6, 9.8, 12.9, 16.5, 19.5, 
    22.1, 22, 18.6, 12.8, 8.5, 6.2, 6.4, 7.4, 9.6, 12.9, 16.6, 
    19.8, 22.8, 22.7, 19, 12.9, 8.5, 5.9, 6.2, 7.5, 10.1, 13.5, 
    17.2, 20.3, 23.1, 23.1, 19.5, 13.4, 8.3, 5.6, 6.2, 7.4, 9.8, 
    13.2, 17.1, 20.2, 22.6, 22.5, 18.9, 12.8, 8.3, 5.8, 6.5, 
    7.5, 9.9, 12.9, 16.7, 19.6, 22.3, 22.1, 18.7, 13, 8.5, 5.9, 
    5.5, 7.4, 10.1, 13.5, 17.2, 20.3, 23.1, 23.5, 20, 13.3, 7.8, 
    5, 4.3, 6.6, 10.5, 14.2, 18.6, 21.9, 25.6, 26.1, 22.4, 14.4, 
    7.3, 3.8, 6.8, 7.8, 10.4, 13.5, 17.1, 19.8, 22.7, 22.9, 19.5, 
    13.6, 9, 6.4, 5.8, 6.9, 9.4, 12.8, 16.5, 19.4, 22.1, 22.3, 
    18.7, 12.6, 7.7, 5.3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), temp_dmin_c = c(0.3, 0, 1.3, 3.9, 6.8, 9.9, 
    11.9, 11.5, 8.2, 5, 2.1, 0.7, -0.3, -0.6, 0.9, 3.1, 6.1, 
    9.3, 11.3, 10.9, 7.5, 4.2, 1.6, 0.2, -0.8, -0.7, 0.7, 2.8, 
    6.2, 9.3, 11.5, 11.1, 7.6, 4, 1, -0.8, -0.5, 0, 1.3, 2.6, 
    6.2, 9, 10.8, 11.1, 7.4, 3.8, 0.6, NA, 1.6, 1.5, 2.8, 4.7, 
    7.7, 10.3, 12.2, 12.2, 9.7, 6.4, 3.1, 1.4, 1.4, 1.2, 2.5, 
    4.6, 8, 11.1, 13.3, 13, 9.9, 6, 2.9, 0.9, 0.7, 0.5, 1.7, 
    3.7, 6.9, 9.8, 11.8, 11.7, 8.6, 5.3, 2.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 
    1.5, 3.4, 6.9, 9.8, 11.7, 11.7, 8.2, 5, 2, 0.5, 1.2, 0.8, 
    2, 4.1, 7.3, 10.1, 11.8, 11.3, 8.4, 5.3, 2.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 
    1.4, 3.5, 6.6, 9.4, 11.5, 11.2, 8.2, 5, 1.9, 0.2, -0.3, -0.6, 
    0.7, 2.7, 6, 9, 10.9, 10.9, 8, 5, 1.8, -0.3, 2.3, 2.4, 3.6, 
    5.6, 8.8, 11.8, 14, 14.3, 11.6, 8, 4.6, 2.2, 1.2, 0.9, 2.3, 
    4.3, 7.3, 10.4, 12.3, 12.1, 9.4, 6.1, 2.8, 0.9, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), rain_mm = c(216, 134.8, 
    127, 90.7, 53, 53, 29.9, 35.4, 45.7, 146.9, 232.3, 236.4, 
    216, 166.8, 149.3, 105, 72.8, 63.2, 42.3, 43.1, 54, 171.8, 
    256.2, 247.3, 194.6, 135.5, 128.4, 91.6, 68.4, 62.9, 39.4, 
    44.6, 55.2, 161, 222.1, 204.2, 186, 140.2, 120.3, 87.2, 58.2, 
    51.3, 35.1, 39, 52.9, 154.8, 228.4, 218.5, 215.2, 135.1, 
    130.8, 93.6, 70.2, 61.1, 39.5, 45.6, 58.7, 168.6, 241, 220.8, 
    159.1, 107.8, 95.7, 64.4, 45.6, 42.8, 26.7, 29.2, 41.8, 122.7, 
    191.9, 168.9, 256.9, 174.1, 151.6, 98, 56.6, 45.2, 26, 37.6, 
    53.6, 189.7, 285.2, 256.7, 182, 144.2, 139.3, 87.2, 64.6, 
    54.7, 36.4, 39, 48.9, 152.9, 228.4, 215.9, 200.6, 131.1, 
    116.3, 79.4, 51.3, 45.3, 26, 34.6, 46.3, 146.8, 214, 180.7, 
    219.3, 150.4, 141, 101.1, 72.1, 62.8, 41.9, 49.5, 59.3, 180.8, 
    249.9, 234.2, 317, 222.7, 215.6, 143.6, 87.8, 62.2, 31, 46.4, 
    61.4, 218.3, 345.2, 323.2, 132, 88.4, 92.4, 70.8, 70.9, 57.4, 
    36.5, 42.3, 51.4, 117.5, 154.9, 134.5, 145.7, 101.9, 104.2, 
    83.2, 76.6, 67.6, 37.5, 45.3, 54.7, 125.5, 171.6, 146.5, 
    185.2, 125.5, 127.8, 99.6, 92.4, 73.7, 46, 50.7, 64.6, 152.1, 
    212.6, 178.5), snow_cm = c(15.9, 9.3, 11.3, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.2, 6, 12.1, 17.3, 10, 6.7, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 
    6.4, 16, 23.3, 14.4, 11.7, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.2, 10.5, 
    22.6, 13.2, 8.4, 7.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 7.3, 14.3, 13.8, 
    6.4, 6.3, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 6, 14.7, 11.9, 6, 9.9, 
    0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 8.2, 18.7, 12.9, 13.3, 8.2, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1.1, 4.8, 15.2, 14.9, 7.8, 4.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.9, 4.1, 8.6, 10.4, 8.8, 4.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.4, 
    4.2, 9.2, 14.8, 10.1, 7.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 7.2, 
    16.5, 22.6, 16.9, 8.2, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6, 8, 21.4, 
    6.1, 4.6, 3.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 3.4, 4.2, 13.6, 7.8, 
    6.8, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 6.5, 11.5, 8.1, 4.8, 2.7, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 4.4, 9), precip_mm = c(231.8, 144.1, 
    138.3, 90.7, 53, 53, 29.9, 35.4, 45.7, 147.1, 238.3, 248.5, 
    233.3, 176.8, 155.9, 105.2, 72.8, 63.2, 42.3, 43.1, 54, 172.9, 
    262.6, 263.3, 217.5, 149.5, 140, 92.1, 68.4, 62.9, 39.4, 
    44.6, 55.2, 162.2, 231.9, 225.7, 198.9, 148.6, 127.9, 87.2, 
    58.2, 51.3, 35.1, 39, 52.9, 155.6, 235.7, 232.8, 229.1, 141.4, 
    137.1, 93.8, 70.2, 61.1, 39.5, 45.6, 58.7, 169.2, 246.9, 
    235.5, 171.9, 114.3, 105.7, 64.6, 45.6, 42.8, 26.7, 29.2, 
    41.8, 122.8, 200.5, 187.9, 269.9, 187.4, 159.8, 98, 56.6, 
    45.2, 26, 37.6, 53.6, 190.8, 290, 272, 196.9, 151.9, 143.9, 
    87.2, 64.6, 54.7, 36.4, 39, 48.9, 153.8, 232.6, 224.5, 211, 
    139.9, 120.6, 79.4, 51.3, 45.3, 26, 34.6, 46.3, 147.2, 218.1, 
    189.8, 234.1, 160.4, 148, 101.2, 72.1, 62.8, 41.9, 49.5, 
    59.3, 181.3, 257.1, 250.7, 339.5, 239.6, 223.8, 144.2, 87.8, 
    62.2, 31, 46.4, 61.4, 219.8, 353.2, 344.6, 138.1, 93.1, 96.1, 
    70.8, 70.9, 57.4, 36.5, 42.3, 51.4, 117.7, 158.3, 138.7, 
    158.9, 109.4, 110.7, 83.3, 76.6, 67.6, 37.5, 45.3, 54.7, 
    125.8, 178, 157.8, 193.3, 130.3, 130.6, 99.6, 92.4, 73.7, 
    46, 50.7, 64.6, 152.3, 216.9, 187.5), date = structure(c(14610, 
    14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
    14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
    14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 
    14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
    14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
    14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 
    14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
    14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
    14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 
    14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
    14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
    14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 
    14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 14610, 
    14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 
    14914, 14944, 14610, 14641, 14669, 14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 
    14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944), class = "Date")), .Names = c("Months", 
"station", "temp_davg_c", "temp_dmax_c", "temp_dmin_c", "rain_mm", 
"snow_cm", "precip_mm", "date"), row.names = c(NA, -168L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is `correct_order`?

Comment: if you stop the pipe after `gather(Legend, Precipitation, -Months)` by removing `%>%`,  you will have the data to be used for the plot in `cn`. Then you can start working with the plot as usual (just substitute `.` with `cn` at the beginning of the `ggplot` line.

Comment: you probably want `fill = legend` rather than `colour = legend` in the `aes`

Comment: Agree with @RichardTelford. You can probably also omit `group = Legend` and save some typing with `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: you guys are totally right! thanks for the input!!!!

Comment: Did you mean to average over your different stations?

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes I wanted to average over all the stations. I'm trying to see what the precipitation situation looks like in that region.  But good point.. Now that I get to think about it. Is there a way to add an "error" bar on top of the stacks to indicate the spread across the stations.. Maybe show one standard deviation as an error bar.. Or show max min on top of the bars?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the dplyr part of your code from the gg-plotting part:

```
correct_order <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

weather_data <- 
  dtt %>% 
  group_by(Months) %>%
  summarise(Rain = mean(rain_mm,na.rm = TRUE),Snow = mean(snow_cm,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  gather(Legend, Precipitation, -Months)

  ggplot(weather_data, aes(x = Months, y = Precipitation, fill = Legend)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=correct_order) + 
  geom_col()
```

As it has been mentioned before, fill= instead of color= is probably what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Dan, okay now I see what you are doing. Yes that totally worked for me! Thanks!